# Put Vaadin component in element generated by Javascript component

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin

I'm creating a Vaadin application for which I'm developing a Javascript component (subclass of `AbstractJavascriptComponent`) that generates, using jQuery, some kind of table.

However, on certain occasions the user needs to be able to enter a value into a cell, for which I would like to use Vaadin's standard `ComboBox` because of the filtering capabilities.  Is this possible?  I know how to make RPC calls from the Javascript component to the server, where I can instantiate the `ComboBox`, but don't see how to add the `ComboBox` to a certain DOM element instead of in a regular layout.

I can't use `Table` or `Grid` because I need to have direct control over the DOM for some complex UI interactions and layout, so please don't suggest to use those instead of creating my own table.  I'm calling it a table here but it's actually more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I think it impossible with Vaadin, but you can create custom HTML layout that will contain Vaadin ComboBox. See CustomLayout https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-customlayout.html

So, you can add necessary behavior for your HTML layout using AbstractJavascriptComponent, but the layout will be static.

If you really want to create this complex container for Vaadin components from scratch you have to create custom Vaadin component in Java that will implement ComponentContainer.

Comment: The problem is I don't need to write static html.  Like I said, I only need to show combo boxes on certain occasions, and the layout is dynamically generated using jQuery.

Comment: Vaadin components have two ways of working: 1. Generate the full solution serverside with Java (Not what you wish) 2. Use the client side components of vaadin. Currently this is only available for a part of the vaadin components, such as Grid. But you would then have to make your own connection to the datasource